# Sqlite with C, verify if data exists in the table

Tags: c, sqlite

I am building an application in C with sqlite database. I have a sqlite database where I stored many ip address(text). If a user inputs an ip address I want my application to check if that ip is inside the database. I could this pretty easy with Python but I cant produce same in C. Please find my code below.

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *res;
int rec_count = 0;
int rc;
char *errMSG;
const char *tail;
char *ip = "192.168.10.10";
int error = sqlite3_open("C:\\botdetect\\IP.db", &db);
if (error)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}

char *sql = "SELECT * FROM ipaddress WHERE IP=?";

sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);
sqlite3_bind_text(res, 1, ip, sizeof(ip), SQLITE_STATIC);
rc = sqlite3_step(res);

printf("rc is %d\n", rc);

sqlite3_finalize(res);
```

Comment: It appears your use of `sizeof(ip)` is wrong. Try `strlen(ip)` or even `-1` instead.

Comment: I did that,its same,i am getting 21 as out put

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Given example outputs `100` for me (which is `SQLITE_ROW`). 21 is `SQLITE_MISUSE`, which is very wrong (e.g. no opened database). If problem persists, consider providing [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error? Is your program crashing? What is the behavior you're seeing?

To progress with troubleshooting (and something that is almost always a good idea), you should check the return values from the `sqlite3_*` calls.

You can find the list of result codes [here](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html). Additionally you can print out a human readable string of the error using the methods provided [here](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

For example to check that the `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` call is succeeding, you can change it to something like:

```
int sqlite_status;
sqlite_status = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);
if (sqlite_status != SQLITE_OK) {
    printf("Error is: %s\n", sqlite3_errstr(sqlite_status));
}
```

You can do something similar with the `sqlite3_bind_text()` call as well as the `sqlite3_step()` call.

*Probably* unrelated to whatever problem you're seeing, is that you define `const char *tail` in order to store a pointer to the unused portion of the SQL statement. You never actually pass this value into the `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` function and instead pass in `0`. I would actually use the variable that you've defined.